# Launch Spring Boot WicketWebApplication inside another java Application without main

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, bukkit

i want to use Spring Boot with Spring Security and Apache Wicket 8.0 as web view.
It`s easy to do it with SpringBoot and just simply run jar file, but i want to do something like this:

Minecraft Server (Spigot, Bukkit, etc..) Scanning /plugins/ folder, and looking for .jar files. 
All files must contain plugin.yml in root of .jar archive. This plugin.yml file contains a path to class file, for example - BukkitMain and this class MUST extend JavaPlugin.
Then MinecraftServer core is executing onEnable() method of BukkitMain.class (so, if we override this method - server code will execute all code inside this method)

For Example:

```
public class BukkitMain extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        //SpringApplicationBuilder.run(....);
    }

}
```

So, i can use Spring-boot-plugin in build part of maven .pom file, but it's packing all class files and resources to BOOT-INF inside jar and it's requiring main(String args[]) method to run SpringApplication.  It`s bad variant, because i can't access my BukkitMain to run it.
When i use Maven Compiler Plugin and packing it to jar - it's all ok, but there is new problem. My BukkitMain trying to run SpringApplicationBuilder, but i'm getting ClassNotFoundException, cause there is no SpringApplicationBuilder inside jar.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve doing this? Can't you run your spring application outside of a bukkit server?

Comment: Yes, i can lauch it, but i want to retrive data from server directly and display it on my pages. It's must me plugin, that starting webService on localhost.
If i launch it separately - i still need somethig like REST service on Bukkit Server side.
One more way - it's Jetty or EmbeddedTomcat, but there is new problems for me, i don`t know how to launch Web App with Spring context, beans, etc and Wicket views as all-in-one jar (Plugin + webService)